# Efficient way to extract expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have large expressions linear in `x`. I would like to take all multiples of `x` off the expressions to have only the remaining terms free of `x`. For example, if I have `U=(y+3z t)x-(5 y^2-t)x+2t^2`, I want to extract and keep `2t^2`. I have tried `U - Coefficient[U,x]`and `Collect[U,x]`, but they take long time given that the expressions are large and I have to use `Simplify` to get the final expression. Is there some efficient way for doing this?

Comment: Why not simply set x to zero: (y+3z t)x-(5 y^2-t)x+2t^2  /. x->0

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks. But some of the terms contain some functions of x and other variables e.g. f[x,y], not sure the effect of setting x to 0 on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) and [`FreeQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FreeQ.html) as follows:

```
Select[FreeQ @ x][ExpandAll @ U]
```

> ```
> 2 t^2
> ```

Comment: Thanks but it is not working. It just gives 0, although the answer is not.

Comment: @Bran, try`Select[FreeQ @ x][ExpandAll @ U]`, If it  does not work,  please update the example in your post with an example `U` that shows the issue.

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Thank you.